# Nothing happens when subscribing in interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor

I want to refresh a token but when the api call is done the token isn't refreshed and i don't see the logs inside it. Here I set a time out go test quickly the refresh then retry to request with the token but nothing happens. It is supposed to add time before expiration.

```
 if (token) {
      authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token),
      });

      const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));

      const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
      console.log(expires);

      const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - 100 * 1000;
      console.log('time', timeout);

      if (timeout >= 0 && timeout <= 19000) {
        
         this.http
          .post<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'refresh', authReq.headers)
          .pipe(
            switchMap((d) => {
              //can't see its content
              console.log(d);
              authReq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token),
              });
          console.log('after: ', expires);

              return next.handle(authReq);
            })
          );
      }
    }
```

If I add this it makes an infinite loop and doesn't refresh. `subscribe();`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the http request like so.

```
return this.http
          .post<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'refresh', authReq.headers)
          .pipe(
```

This will cause the request to fire. The reason your console log isn't firing at all is because the http request isn't being triggered.

Also use a `map()`. You don't need a `switchMap()`

Comment: If I add subscribe() it makes an infinite loop.

Comment: where are you calling the code that you provided? Does it expect you to return a subscription? You're also returning inside the pipe but since you don't return the outer subscription. You won't get anything out.

Comment: I call it in the interceptor so everytime there is a request it fires. I just want to know if the token is refreshed so i think I have to subscribe to know it.

Comment: Are your two console.log statements firing?

Comment: the console.log() in the switchMap() don't fire at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227969/discussion-between-james-and-leri).

Comment: It fires but the logs aren't displayed neither